# HAWQ. join in/out rows by in/out time

Tags: postgresql, hawq, bigdata

HAWQ. How to join in/out rows by in/out time?

simple

[image]

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the second row be id_in of 3, not 4?  Your sample data has 4 "in" records for car_id=1 but 3 out records.  How did you determine that it should be id=4 instead of id=3?

Comment: Currently i'm cleaning the data.
While 'in' was on 18 and 25 February, 'out' is only at 27.
so i'm removing 18th entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve.  The trick is to use the window function "row_number()".

```
select sub1.car_id, sub1.id_in, sub1.cross_date_time_in, sub2.id_out, sub2.cross_date_time_out 
from (
      select car_id, id as id_in, 
             cross_date_time as cross_date_time_in, 
             row_number() over (partition by car_id order by cross_date_time) as row_num
      from source_table
      where direction = 'in') as sub1
      join (select car_id, id as id_out, 
                   cross_date_time as cross_date_time_out, 
                   row_number() over (partition by car_id order by cross_date_time) as row_num
            from source_table
            where direction = 'out') as sub2 on sub1.car_id = sub2.car_id and sub1.row_num = sub2.row_num;
```

You can write this with common table expressions too if you prefer that format.

```
with sub1 as (select car_id, id as id_in, cross_date_time as cross_date_time_in, 
              row_number() over (partition by car_id order by cross_date_time) as row_num
              from source_table
              where direction = 'in'),
     sub2 as (select car_id, id as id_out, cross_date_time as cross_date_time_out, 
              row_number() over (partition by car_id order by cross_date_time) as row_num
              from source_table
              where direction = 'out')
select sub1.car_id, sub1.id_in, sub1.cross_date_time_in, 
       sub2.id_out, sub2.cross_date_time_out
from sub1
join sub2 on sub1.car_id = sub2.car_id and sub1.row_num = sub2.row_num;
```

Comment: Thank's 
Unfortunately, it does not give the correct result.
Wrong result.
1 1 2017-02-12 10:20:15.000000 1 2017-02-09 10:20:15.000000

Answer (score 0):

```html
create table source_table
(
  id INT
  ,car_id INT
  ,direction text
  ,cross_date_time TIMESTAMP
);
insert into source_table
    values (1, 1,'in', to_timestamp('2017-02-02-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 1,'in', to_timestamp('2017-02-12-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 1,'in', to_timestamp('2017-02-18-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));;
insert into source_table
    values (1, 1,'in', to_timestamp('2017-02-25-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 1,'out', to_timestamp('2017-02-08-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 1,'out', to_timestamp('2017-02-09-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 1,'out', to_timestamp('2017-02-27-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 2,'in', to_timestamp('2017-02-02-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 2,'in', to_timestamp('2017-02-12-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 2,'in', to_timestamp('2017-02-18-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 2,'out', to_timestamp('2017-02-08-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 2,'out', to_timestamp('2017-02-14-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 2,'out', to_timestamp('2017-02-27-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 2,'out', to_timestamp('2017-02-29-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 3,'in', to_timestamp('2017-02-02-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 3,'in', to_timestamp('2017-02-12-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 3,'out', to_timestamp('2017-02-08-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));
insert into source_table
    values (1, 3,'out', to_timestamp('2017-02-14-10:20:15', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss'));



select sub1.car_id, sub1.id_in, sub1.cross_date_time_in, sub2.id_out, sub2.cross_date_time_out
from (
      select car_id, id as id_in,
             cross_date_time as cross_date_time_in,
             row_number() over (partition by car_id order by cross_date_time) as row_num
      from source_table
      where direction = 'in') as sub1
     join (select car_id, id as id_out,
                   cross_date_time as cross_date_time_out,
                   row_number() over (partition by car_id order by cross_date_time) as row_num
            from source_table
            where direction = 'out') as sub2 on sub1.car_id = sub2.car_id and sub1.row_num = sub2.row_num;
```

Wrong result.

1 1 2017-02-12 10:20:15.000000 1 2017-02-09 10:20:15.000000

if use a left join variant:

```html
select sub1.car_id, sub1.id_in, sub1.cross_date_time_in, sub2.id_out, sub2.cross_date_time_out
from (
      select car_id, id as id_in,
             cross_date_time as cross_date_time_in,
             row_number() over (partition by car_id order by cross_date_time) as row_num
      from source_table
      where direction = 'in') as sub1
     left join (select car_id, id as id_out,
                   cross_date_time as cross_date_time_out,
                   row_number() over (partition by car_id order by cross_date_time) as row_num
            from source_table
            where direction = 'out') as sub2 on sub1.car_id = sub2.car_id and sub1.row_num = sub2.row_num;
```

wrong results:
1              1              2017-02-12 10:20:15.000000         1              2017-02-09 10:20:15.000000
1              1              2017-02-18 10:20:15.000000         1              2017-02-27 10:20:15.000000
1              1              2017-02-25 10:20:15.000000

Comment: You changed the question slightly by using a constant value for id but the more important note is you haven't described the business logic.  I'm guessing.  It looks like you are simply ordering the in and out rows and match based matching car_id and the order in which they appear based on date.